# .NET Version Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

Have a problem with the .NET version installed on my server. In my local machine I have the version 4.7.3324.0 installed (the clr.dll file have that number for the product name and product version)

My server had 4.0 and upgrade to 4.6.1 (the clr.dll file now have File Version = 4.6.81.0 and product version = 4.0.30319.0)

The thing is, the asp.net web page works fine in my local machine but in the server it does't. We had to upgrade to use the TLs12 but even with the upgrade I'm unable to make it work (I'm setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`).

Any ideas?

Thank you

`System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving
the HTTP response to https://myservice/webservices/current/logon.asmx. This could be due to theservi ice endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
(possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected 
error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common 
algorithm`

Comment: "because they do not possess a common algorithm" That's an issue with TLS handshakes.

Comment: Yes.. but why is working on my local machine (win 10)? I tried in another server with windows server 2012 and works fine

Comment: The server where is not working in windows server 2008 SP2